# Reedirigir un boton a un form c#

Tags: c#

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Quiero saber como iria el codigo para que al presionar el boton, el form actual desaparezca y aparezca uno nuevo que se llama

```
private void NewConfiguration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

De ante mano, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el primer form podrias poner

```
private void button1_Click(...){

    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    frm2.Show();

}
```

Con eso abres el form

luego en el Form que se abre para regresar solo lo cierras o en un boton del mismo pones

```
private void btnClose_Click(...){

   this.Close();

}
```